# How to restrict a record to a specific team in crm?

Tags: permissions, dynamics-crm

I have an Entity name category1, that category1 is a lookup entity on my phonecall entity. My user needs to choose from the lookup field a category to catalogue the phonecall.   I need that a specific record (from category1) will be available only to a specific team and only that specific team will be able to choose that category from the lookup field.

When I created the category record I set the owner as a specific team and I added the same team to my user, but users that don't have the team are able to choose that category. What am I missing? I need to restrict my category record to all entities in the system not to a specific view, according to team.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct. Except check the Read privilege of that particular entity in all security roles.. it should be user level not anything more than that (like BU, Org).

Comment: Hey Arun,I don't need to restrict an entity, only  a record. one specific record to a specific team. only that team can use that record, thanks.

Comment: @Damkulul what do you think the difference between Entity & it’s record? You said that you have already assigned that record to team & added user to the team.. do you want to share the record to team so object based security concept will apply..?